# std::list transform and copy

Tags: c++, stl

I need make the following algorithm:

```
(Pseudocode)
lsi = (set_1, set_2, ..., set_n) # list of sets.
answer = [] // vector of lists of sets
For all set_i in lsi:
   if length(set_i) > 1:
        for all x in set_i:
            A = set_i.discard(x)
            B = {x}
            answer.append( (set_1, ..., set_{i-1}, A, B, set_{i+1}, ..., set_n) )
```

For example, let lsi = ({1,2},{3}, {4,5}).

Then ansver = [({1},{2},{3},{4,5}), ({2},{1},{3},{4,5}), ({1,2},{3},{4},{5}), ({1,2},{3},{5},{4})].

I'm trying to do it (C++), but I can't.
My code:

```
list<set<int>> lsi {{1, 2}, {3}, {4, 5}}; 

// Algorithm
vector<list<set<int>>> answer;
for (list<set<int>>::iterator it_lsi = lsi.begin(); it_lsi != lsi.end(); it_lsi++)
{
    for (set<int>::iterator it_si = (*it_lsi).begin(); it_si != (*it_lsi).end(); it_lsi++)
    {
        // set_i = *it_lsi, 
        // x = *it_si.
        // Creating sets A and B.
        set<int> A = *it_lsi;
        A.erase(*it_si); // A = set_i.discard(x)
        set<int> B;
        B.insert(*it_si); // B = {x}
        // Creating list which have these sets.
        list<set<int>> new_lsi;
        new_lsi.push_back(s1);
        new_lsi.push_back(s2);
        /*
        And I don't know what should I do :-(
        Object lsi must be immutable (because it connect with generator). 
        Splice transform it. Other ways I don't know.
        */
    }
}
```

Could you help me?
Thank you.

Comment: Aren't you accumulating your results in `answer`? I don't understand why  you would need to call `splice` on `lsi`.

Comment: Consider using [`auto`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) and [ranged based for loops](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) to greatly simplify your example. It will save you from having to write out iterator type names in the future.

Comment: >  I don't understand why you would need to call splice on lsi 

If the splice didn't transform `lsi`, I could do this: 

 new_lsi.splice (new_lsi.begin(), lsi, it_lsi); 
 
Unfortunately, it transform `lsi`.

Comment: [`std::set::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert) can be used to insert a range of elements from another container. `std::set` also doesn't have a splice method. Perhaps you meant [`std::set::merge`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/merge)?

Comment: `list<set<int>> new_lsi{lsi.begin(), it_lsi}; new_lsi.push_back(A); new_lsi.push_back(B); new_lsi.insert(new_lsi.end(), std::next(it_lsi), lsi.end());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list<set<int>> lsi {{1, 2}, {3}, {4, 5}}; 

vector<list<set<int>>> answer;
for (auto it_lsi = lsi.begin(); it_lsi != lsi.end(); ++it_lsi)
{
    if (it_lsi->size() > 1)
        for (int i : *it_lsi)
        {
            list<set<int>> res {lsi.begin(), it_lsi};
            set<int> A = *it_lsi;
            A.erase(i);
            set<int> B {i};
            res.push_back(A);
            res.push_back(B);
            res.insert(res.end(), next(it_lsi), lsi.end());
            answer.push_back(res);
        }
}
```

Runnable code with simple output: http://ideone.com/y2x35Q

Comment: Thank you, great.